# Real Time update Google Chart,php,mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have project temperatures mesuare on beaglebone using mySQL to store data.
I was able to display the google chart form mysql using php but I can't realtime update it, Can anyone help me,thanks so much.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>BeagleBone Temperature</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Time', 'Temperature'],
            <?php
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "hoangviet", "hoangviet", "test");

                $query = "SELECT * FROM TempMeas"; // form table
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                mysqli_close($con);

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $time = $row['MeasTime'];
                    $temp = $row['Temp'];
                    echo "['$time', $temp],";
                }
            ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'BeagleBone Measured Temperature',
          vAxis: { title: "Degrees Celsius" }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Realtime update means you wish to update it without refresh?

Comment: that's right, can you help me.

Comment: You need to call ajax at every 30 secs for that.It will be synchronous way.

Comment: setInterval(function() {
  drawChart()
 }, 5000); i do like this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I guess reverse ajax will suit your need. One type of it would be polling, wherein you don't need to call a function thru ajax every 30 secs or something. It'll update right after an event or something that triggers the functions. There are lot's of option nowadays doing real time apps, one would be node.js also angular js, you can also read on socket programming if you want to implement real time web application. Hope that helps.